# iOS Swift 3: NetworkIndicator won't show itself upon connecting to server

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm developing an app for iOS 10 with Swift 3.

Currently I'm trying to show the NetWork Indicator in the status bar while the app is connecting to a server in the background (solved with a DispatchQueue).

My problem is that the Indicator isn't showing it self.
This is the code that should shows the indicator and connects to the server(connecting needs aprox 5seconds):

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true);

    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true;
    Queue.async {
        communication.sharedInstance.initCommunication(address: "195.202.147.81", port: 1217)
    }
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false;


}
```

Comment: What do you think that `async { ... }` does? You switch the indicator off before the communication even has started. – You can verify that easily be single-stepping through the code, or adding `print` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` to `false` directly so you wont have time to see it. Set it to false when the connection is done instead.

Comment: Got it! 
Just moved the `UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true` to the function that connects my app, now it works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

You should use this code

```
Queue.async {
    communication.sharedInstance.initCommunication(address: "195.202.147.81", port: 1217)

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Update: I think it should be written like this

Comment: I moved it to the `InitCommunication` function. What are the advantages of your solution?

Comment: Once communication is done in background we have to go to main queue to update the UI.